# NetValidatePasswordPolicy ignoring password history

Tags: active-directory

I'm using `NetValidatePasswordPolicy` to validate a password against policy. It works for password length and password complexity, but for some reason it doesn't validate at all against history, allowing my application to repeatedly set the same password on the same user over and over. I fear the answer is similar to .NET's SetPassword method, which will only enforce history if the code is running *as* the user it is validating against. As I'm running this from a web service, that option is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the NetValidatePasswordPolicy API this is stated to not do any history checking.

The NetValidatePasswordPolicy function does not validate passwords in Active Directory accounts and cannot be used for this purpose. The only policy that this function checks a password against in Active Directory accounts is the password complexity (the password strength).